# why this logic validation pass in springboot

Tags: java, rest, boolean, notnull

help me. im beginning level developer.

this is springboot env.

i made a simple rest api server.

```
@PutMapping(value="/mode", consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Response> Mode( @RequestBody @Valid Response res) {
   <logic>
  return new ResponseEntity<Response>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and object class here.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Response{
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("right_val")   //json , DB field name
    private boolean value;
}
```

right_val is mandatory parameter by requestBody.

requestBody => {"right_val":"true"}  is successful result.

but i tested by postman as below sample.

requestBody => {}

but this is not occur error. {} like as "right_val"="false"  in my spring boot.

how to solve checking  mandatory parameter of boolean type in springboot rest api.

Comment: a primitive type can not be null. a booleans default value is false, not null. You should study the basics before trying to work with frameworks like spring

Comment: @Stultuske thank you !!  i'm confusing it.